# Converting attachment to image

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Up to know i can load the attachments to memory and i know its right cause i can print the name of the file. What i need is to convert this attachment to an image object which i will later add to a sharepoint picture library. But forget about the sharepoint part i know how to do that, am stuck in the part that after loading the attachments how do i conver this into images. I dont want to save the images in disk cause thats not the point i already load them in memory.

```
         foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
              if (item is EmailMessage && item.HasAttachments)
                {
                  EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
                   foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                        {
                           FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                            // Load the file attachment into memory and print out its file name.
                            fileAttachment.Load();
                            Console.WriteLine("Attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
                          //this is where i would create the image of object but dont know how
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the FileAttachment object, and you even access one of its properties. You only need to take the next step, and access not only the `Name` but also the `Content`.

```
if (attachment is FileAttachment)
{
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
    fileAttachment.Load();
    byte[] fileContent = fileAttachment.Content;
}
```

This will give you the contents on the attachemnts, as an array of bytes. I don't remember what the Sharepoint API wants to receive, but it's either this byte array or something you can easily build out of it.

Comment: thanks just what i needed, and yes the sharepoint picture library receives an array of bytes. Thanks for your response!

Comment: i have parse the html from the email using the htmlagilitypack api. It works great as it extracts the src value from all the in the email. Problem is that the images that are in the attachment and display in the email its src are parse like: cid:companylogo, cid:forumlogo. the idea is that after i upload the attachment image to the sharepoint library i take that url and replace with the one in the html. Problem is that i dont know which src to replace. Dunno why the src = cid:forumlogo, and not the name of the file in the attachment. Any ideas?

Comment: You should start a new question for this, since it's a different topic.

Comment: nevermind lol found out of the .contentId attribute in the documentation thanks anyways